# Conflicting problem with css

Tags: html, css

I was told last night that the following isn't allowed in CSS.

```
<a href="index.php"><div class="button">Home</div></a>

.submenu div.button{width:72px; height:20px; float:left; margin:0 20px; font-size:0.9em; font-family:Arial; padding:2px; color:black;}
```

How can i create the look I want for the button and then allow the user to click on it in any other way? What is the best way to do this?

It works as it is, but I am being told it's not complient.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't allowed in CSS"?

Comment: He means the `div` inside the `a`

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean.

Comment: This is not a CSS problem, but a HTML problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS is perfectly valid, what isn't allowed is nesting block level elements inside inline elements. So, in your case, it's illegal to insert a `<div>` inside an `<a>`. You can leave the `<div>` out altogether and style the `<a>` element instead and give it `display: block` for it to behave like a block level element.

```
<a href="index.php" class="button">Home</a>

.submenu a.button{
    display: block;
    width: 72px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: What's the practical consequences of violating this rule?

Comment: Consequences may not be very practical, most browsers probably handle that just fine either way. But the behaviour is undefined in the spec and might lead to uneven rendering on different browsers. And it won't validate.

Answer (score 1):

something like this may achieve what you want with minimal fuss.

```
<div class="submenu">
    <a class="button" href="index.php">Home</a>
</div>

.submenu a.button{
    width:72px; 
    height:20px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0 20px; 
    font-size:0.9em; 
    font-family:Arial; 
    padding:2px; 
    color:black;

    display:block; /*added */
}
```

The anchor will be overqualified , just`.submenu a {}` would  suffice, but this depends if you wish to have other, un-styled links in the .submenu div.

*edit* also - can't really tell from your provided markup, but you'll probably want to use an unordered list for "semantic" markup. mine is just an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span instead of the div...
Or you can use display:block for the a tag und style the a tag...